# Use iOS accessibility sounds programmatically

Tags: ios, audio, accessibility, voiceover, accessibility-api

I am aware that one can programmatically use the text-to-speech synthesizer in iOS through the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` class.

However the non-visual interaction with the iOS is based on speech as well as non-speech sound. For instance each time an app is selected a short "tick" sound is heard together with VoiceOver uttering the name of the app.

I was wondering whether there is an Objective-C API that allows to programmatically reproduce those sounds as well, together with the speech.

Answer (score 0):

No API for this, file a bug ;-)